# I am unable to switch to popup window in c# selenium

Tags: selenium, c#

I have to create a new record, for that a new popup window opens. so i am unable to switch to that window.
I used this code to switch the popup window

```
foreach (string handle in driver.WindowHandles) {
    IWebDriver popup = driver.SwitchTo().Window(handle);
    if (popup.Title.Contains("New Document Set: Project")) {
        break;
    }
}
```

This is the element where I need to enter the data

**HTML Snippet**

```
<input type="text" value="" maxlength="256" id="FileLeafRef_8553196d-ec8d-4564-9861-3dbe931050c8_$onetidIOFile" title="Name Required Field" class="ms-long" size="35">
```

**Code tried**

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("FileLeafRef_8553196d-ec8d-4564-9861-3dbe931050c8_$onetidIOFilert")).SendKeys("NewprojectTest");
```

Comment: Can someone please suggest the solution to this issue. both of above options does not work for me.

Comment: This is looks like it's being generated on the fly. What is your error?
Try searching it no via ID but via CssSelector or Xpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@santhosh - 
Seems you're unable to handle pop-up and switch on new/child window. You can consider child = pop-up window and parent = your actual window. Its just we need to redirect control properly.

```
    Set <String> handles =driver.getWindowHandles();
    Iterator<String> it = handles.iterator();

    String parent = it.next();
    String child = it.next();

    driver.switchTo().window(child);

    //perform actions

    driver.close(); // only for child


    driver.switchTo().window(parent);

    //perform actions

    driver.quit(); // After execution of main thread and for parent window
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not focused in the right window. With this case you want to use:

```
driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles.Last());
```

`Last()` will switch to the most recently opened window which should be the one you just clicked.